# JTabbedPane - ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, jtabbedpane

Im adding and removing tabs in JTabbedPane dynamically. Code:

```
     //Method which adds new tab  
     private void addTab(String title, MainPanel panel) {
        tabbed.addTab(title, panel);
        int index = tabbed.indexOfComponent(panel);
        JPanel tabPanel = new JPanel();
        tabPanel.setOpaque(false);
        tabPanel.add(panel.getLabel());
        JButton closeButton = new JButton(new CloseTabAc(index));
        tabPanel.add(closeButton);
        panel.getLabel().setText(title);
        tabbed.setTabComponentAt(index, tabPanel);
        tabbed.setSelectedIndex(index);
        currentPanel = panel;
    }

//Action to close tab
private class CloseTabAc extends AbstractAction {

    private int tabNum;

    CloseTabAc(int tabNum) {
        putValue(Action.NAME, "x");
        this.tabNum = tabNum;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MainPanel panel = (MainPanel) tabbed.getComponentAt(tabNum);
                tabbed.remove(tabNum);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

So this is the code. When switching, removing tabs I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:604)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:382)
    at javax.swing.JTabbedPane.getComponentAt(JTabbedPane.java:1224)
    at jnotepad.MainFrame$CloseTabAc$1.run(MainFrame.java:247)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    ...
```

Im trying to solve it few days but I dont see whats wrong. The only I saw this error occurs in situation when I open few tabs and close them randomly. So eg. I open 3 tabs: 1, 2 and 3. If I close them in order: 3, 2, 1 I get exception but everything close. But when I try to close them in order: 3, 1, 2 then 3 will close but on 1 exception will be thrown and it wont close now or then. So please help me solve my problem.

**EDIT:** I modified my code according to Jean's solution and now I get following exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(ArrayList.java:371)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:384)
    at javax.swing.JTabbedPane.getComponentAt(JTabbedPane.java:1224)
    at jnotepad.MainFrame$ChangeHandler.stateChanged(MainFrame.java:228)
    at javax.swing.JTabbedPane.fireStateChanged(JTabbedPane.java:416)
    at javax.swing.JTabbedPane$ModelListener.stateChanged(JTabbedPane.java:270)
    ...
```

Looks exception is in line 228. It's my stateChanged listener:

```
   private class ChangeHandler implements ChangeListener {
        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent ev) {
            currentPanel = (MainPanel) tabbed.getComponentAt(tabbed.getSelectedIndex());
        }
    }
```

Every tab has MainPanel instance in it. When another tab is selected I get this panel and set is as currentPanel in MainFrame. This exception doesnt break my GUI as previous one but Id like to get rid of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have three tabs

| tab 0 | tab 1 | tab 2 |

if you remove tab 1, tab 2 index will be 1. That's why you get a `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Pass a reference to the tab item, not its index on the tabbed pane, to the listener.

Comment: Thanks it helped but there's another exception now (take a look at my edit). What can cause it?

Comment: Looks like the listener was called from the tab you removed, and no tab is selected yet. Try checking if tabbed.getSelectedIndex() returns a value withing the range (>=0 and < tabbed pane size). If it doesn't work, put your code here...